# Excel Formula/Tip for data in a required format from the raw data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, report

I have an excel sheet with raw data, student results, multiple students with multiple topics, and each topic has preevaluation and post evalautions on each topic.  They also have lessons which dont have scores.  I need to make a report in this format, Student, columns having different topic names, in the row, whether it is post or preevalaution, and corresponding entering the scores acheived.  I have all this data in raw data sheet. only thing is it is not in required format.  How do i do this? pls help

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you need as we can't see the data and it's format but it seems a pivot should do the job with "Student Name" and "Pre/ Post Evaluation flag" as the row labels. The "topic" could be the column labels. The "score" or "result" would be the values.

Using the classic excel pivot style might look better but it's up to you.